# jQuery target LinkedIn share button

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api, jquery-events

I have a LinkedIn share button which I need to target with jQuery to save what content was shared etc. I've done the same with Twitter, which has an api for capturing events, but I'm having a problem with LinkedIn. Since it's not an iframe, I figured I can catch events. This is the initial code:

```
<li id="linkedin-share">
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
        lang: en_US
    </script>
    <script type="IN/Share"></script>
</li>
```

So, sharing works fine, but I can't capture the click. I've managed to capture the rendered html elements in Chrome DevTool's console, but I didn't manage to capture a click. I've tried something like this:

```
$('<fixed parent>').on('click', '<rendered content catchable in devtools>', function(){
    console.log('captured');
});
```

Any ideas, is there some predefined way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="IN/Share" data-onSuccess="shared"></script>

function shared(){
     console.log('shared');
}
```

hacky solution

```
jQuery('#tester').click(function(){

    //share function here!
    IN.UI.Share().params({
    url: "http://www.example.com"
    }).place()
});
```

Link to docs: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui unfortunately no event for successful share.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happens, nothing gets written in the console

Comment: Turns out data-onsuccess/data-success don't work because it's a (know) LinkedIn bug, reported first in 2011 and then again in April 2014. It hasn't been fixed since..

Comment: yes i see that now...used to work...not much you can do with it so. I updated a hacky solution but obviously it won't detect if the user actually shared.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is just sharing on LinkedIn, then why rely on their API to do the sharing?  You should be able to do this as a simple direct link:

```
<a id="share-on-linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Frevoltlib.com%2F">Share On LinkedIn</a>
```

Then you'll be able to control the element directly, like any other element, like so:

```
$('#share-on-linkedin').click(function(e) {});
```

Source: **[Official Microsoft Linkedin Share Plugin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.